# How to structure this design in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to rebuild the app from the screenshot.

In the main view there are different sections, each containing an title and a list (tableview). What is the best way to build this design in Swift? Using collectionview cells or using a tableview with sections and a different section head view? Or is there a better way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Table view, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a perfect situation for the use of a tableView, with a different cell design (not a section header) for the first cell in each section.  If you don't want any of the tableView functionality you could do it with two stackviews, but it would probably be harder work.

Comment: Okay, how do I create the shadow and spacing between the tableview sections?

Comment: if you want to copy it that closely then you'll struggle with a default tableView, and will have to get a bit more creative in the UI.  It'll depend on what functionality you want, whether number of rows is static, if you want to do anything with the cells or just display them etc etc.  Maybe two ungrouped tableView in container views, 2 stackviews in container views, two stackviews nested in another stackview.  You need to do your design work, work out your _full_ set of requirements and then match them to the possible UI options.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please ask only one question per topic. See also here: [ask]